# Classification with fuzzy logic

Tags: classification, fuzzy-logic

Is there any video, paper or example which explain steps of classification with fuzzy logic. I am trying to make something in matlab but I couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, there is some paper or video, that can help solve something. What kind of question is it?

Comment: i have some data which got from sensors and i have 9 class.

Comment: if you clarify your problem, maybe you can get some help. I also leave you this bibliography: L. Reznik, Fuzzy Controllers. Australia: Newnes, 1997. Hope this helps.